# Render content returned from an API in child window electron react application

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-react

I have an electron react application, the scenario I’m unable to get it to work is, on the main window, on clicking a button, I want to call the main process which makes a gRPC call to an external server, gets data back and renders the data in a child window.

I’m able to do this on the same window and it works fine, but I can’t wrap my head around on how to take the data that the main process returns and render a react component in a new window using the returned data.

Comment: Here's what I have done so far:

On the first react page to pass data from:
window.electronAPI.passInfo(args);


On main.js
ipcMain.on('pass-info', (_event, args: any) => {
  console.log('pass-info', args);

  const childWindow = createWindow('child', {
    width: 1000,
    height: 600,
  });
  const port = process.argv[2];
  childWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  childWindow.loadURL(`http://localhost:${port}/test`);
  childWindow.webContents.send('pass-info-response', args);
});

Comment: On the second react page: Here if I don't put it inside useEffect, I get window is not defined error, so I am not sure about that.
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Test');

    window.electronAPI.passInfoResponse((event, data) => {
      console.log(event, data);
    });
  }, []);


Here's my preload.js
  passInfo: (args: any) => ipcRenderer.send('pass-info', args),
  passInfoResponse: (callback: any) => {
    console.log('inside preload');
    return ipcRenderer.on('pass-info-response', callback);
  },